# Using the .h5 file is not giving the expected output?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, keras

I'm currently using Flask in order to combine backend and frontend form image classification. I'm also using .h5 file in order to predict the output. The output is different and is fully wrong. The output should be the prediction probability. Here is the code:

```py
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the file from post request
        f = request.files['file']

        # Save the file to ./uploads
        basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        file_path = os.path.join(
            basepath, 'uploads', secure_filename(f.filename))
        f.save(file_path)

        MODEL_ARCHITECTURE = 'model_adam_01.json'
        MODEL_WEIGHTS = 'model_50_eopchs_adam_01.h5'

        json_file = open(MODEL_ARCHITECTURE)
        loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
        json_file.close()
        model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
        model.load_weights(MODEL_WEIGHTS)
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
        prediction = model_predict(file_path, model)
        print("I think that is ")
        print(prediction)
        # print('I think that is {}.'.format(predicted_class.lower()))
        return str(prediction)
```

Following is the model_predict function where I have passed the image path and the model

```py
def model_predict(img_path, model):
    '''
        Args:
            -- img_path : an URL path where a given image is stored.
            -- model : a given Keras CNN model.
    '''

    IMG = image.load_img(img_path)
    print(type(IMG))

    IMG_ = np.asarray(IMG)
    print(type(IMG_))

    print(IMG_.shape)

    IMG_ = prepare(IMG_)
    print(IMG_.shape)
    #print(model)

    prediction = model.predict(IMG_)
    print(prediction.shape)

    return str(prediction)
```

Following is the output that I am getting:

```py
I think that is
[[0.]]
```

Why does this problem occur? I am using keras 2.3.1 and tesorflow 1.15.2

Answer (score 0):

When doing the predictions you have to apply the same preprocessing steps that you did to your training data just before training the model. I think that should be the problem rather than the code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have used the same preprocessing steps which i had used for training the model but still its giving the same output.@Galo Castillo